# show empty on Empty text: PHP code View

Tags: views, 6

1. I have a View that shows the user's latest posts on his/her profile.
2. If the user has no posts and it's own profile it show a link to encourage forum posting.
3. If the user has no posts and it's someone else's profile, the view should not be there.

Currently the first 2 are ok, but the last one is not returning as expected. I'm getting an empty div (styled).

In the view's Empty text I have PHP code:

```
<?php
    global $user;
    if (something_get_username_from_url_alias() == $user->name) {
        echo '<span>You have no forum posts</span><br>';
        echo l('Go do some posting', 'forum');
    } // else scenario where block not shown
?>
```

If the question is not clear, please let me know.
Thank you.

```
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Self Profile: User Posts', 'block_3');
$handler->override_option('fields', array(
  'subject' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'absolute' => 0,
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'rel' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'hide_alter_empty' => 1,
    'link_to_comment' => 1,
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'subject',
    'table' => 'comments',
    'field' => 'subject',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Use default',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'timestamp' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'absolute' => 0,
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'rel' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'hide_alter_empty' => 1,
    'date_format' => 'raw time ago',
    'custom_date_format' => '',
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'timestamp',
    'table' => 'comments',
    'field' => 'timestamp',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Use default',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('sorts', array(
  'timestamp' => array(
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'granularity' => 'second',
    'id' => 'timestamp',
    'table' => 'comments',
    'field' => 'timestamp',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Use default',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('arguments', array(
  'name' => array(
    'default_action' => 'default',
    'style_plugin' => 'default_summary',
    'style_options' => array(),
    'wildcard' => 'all',
    'wildcard_substitution' => 'All',
    'title' => '',
    'breadcrumb' => '',
    'default_argument_type' => 'php',
    'default_argument' => '',
    'validate_type' => 'none',
    'validate_fail' => 'empty',
    'glossary' => 0,
    'ignorecase' => 0,
    'limit' => '0',
    'case' => 'none',
    'path_case' => 'none',
    'transform_dash' => 0,
    'id' => 'name',
    'table' => 'comments',
    'field' => 'name',
    'validate_user_argument_type' => 'uid',
    'validate_user_roles' => array(
      2 => 0,
      4 => 0,
      3 => 0,
      5 => 0,
      6 => 0,
    ),
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Use default',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
    'default_options_div_prefix' => '',
    'default_taxonomy_tid_term_page' => 0,
    'default_taxonomy_tid_node' => 0,
    'default_taxonomy_tid_limit' => 0,
    'default_taxonomy_tid_vids' => array(
      1 => 0,
      8 => 0,
      3 => 0,
      34 => 0,
      33 => 0,
      32 => 0,
      31 => 0,
      7 => 0,
      6 => 0,
    ),
    'default_argument_user' => 0,
    'default_argument_fixed' => '',
    'default_argument_php' => 'return something_get_username_from_url_alias();',
    'validate_argument_node_type' => array(
      'magento_group' => 0,
      'magento_product_4' => 0,
      'magento_product_4_global' => 0,
      'magento_product_4_website' => 0,
      'magento_store' => 0,
      'magento_website' => 0,
      'forum' => 0,
      'article' => 0,
      'blog' => 0,
      'expert' => 0,
      'ingredient' => 0,
      'page' => 0,
      'profile' => 0,
      'recipe' => 0,
      'webform' => 0,
    ),
    'validate_argument_node_access' => 0,
    'validate_argument_nid_type' => 'nid',
    'validate_argument_vocabulary' => array(
      1 => 0,
      8 => 0,
      3 => 0,
      34 => 0,
      33 => 0,
      32 => 0,
      31 => 0,
      7 => 0,
      6 => 0,
    ),
    'validate_argument_type' => 'tid',
    'validate_argument_transform' => 0,
    'validate_user_restrict_roles' => 0,
    'validate_argument_node_flag_name' => '*relationship*',
    'validate_argument_node_flag_test' => 'flaggable',
    'validate_argument_node_flag_id_type' => 'id',
    'validate_argument_user_flag_name' => '*relationship*',
    'validate_argument_user_flag_test' => 'flaggable',
    'validate_argument_user_flag_id_type' => 'id',
    'validate_argument_php' => 'return true;',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('filters', array());
$handler->override_option('empty', '<?php
    global $user;
    if (something_get_username_from_url_alias() == $user->name) {
        echo \'<span>You have no forum posts</span><br>\';
        echo l(\'Go do some posting\', \'forum\');
    } // else scenario where block not shown
?>');
$handler->override_option('empty_format', '3');
$handler->override_option('items_per_page', 5);
$handler->override_option('row_plugin', 'fields');
$handler->override_option('row_options', array());
$handler->override_option('block_description', '');
$handler->override_option('block_caching', -1);
```

Comment: Note, you could use [menu_get_object('user')](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/6) to get the user object from user/uid system path and check username there

Comment: I'll check that out, thanks for the tip @DavidThomas... But that wont solve my issue =(... Anyone knows about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the No Results Behaviour (of type Text) under the Advanced section within the Views Module.
2. In the text part of the behaviour, add your code

   if (something_get_username_from_url_alias() == $user->name) {
       echo 'You have no forum posts
   ';
       echo l('Go do some posting', 'forum');
   } // else scenario where block not shown
   else {
     echo 'Nothing to see here...
   ';
   }

Comment: That would solve point 3 but null point 2 =(

Comment: You could add a Text Area (as the No result behaviour), and add PHP code to check if the profile belongs to the current user.

Comment: The textarea would not really change my situation, because I need for case 3 to be empty. If you see my code there, you will see that I am already validating if the the profile belongs to the current user.

Comment: If User has posts -> View Displays
If User has no posts, and is current user -> Show Text (which is PHP code to show link)
Else -> Show Nothing.

You paste your text into the behaviour.

Comment: That part is working... if user has posts they are displaying just fine... the problem is that when the user has no posts, there are 2 options... Either its his own profile and he sees (Go post link) or its someone else's profile and nothing is shown (only that Views returns some white space inside a div)

Comment: I believe I understand your problem. Copy the PHP code you have into a No results behaviour and check that the code executes.

Comment: Yep. So if there are are no results, the No Results Behaviour is added, and that "behaviour" contains the PHP code you have above which decides whether to add text, or leave the DIV blank.

Comment: exactly... so... is there anyway to not put the div par if it's going to be empty?